# Will code inside a preprocessor conditional enter the binary?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, c-preprocessor

I have a Config.h file which includes various preprocessor conditionals based on the environment. The project has 2 targets. Via the preprocessor arguments, if the environment is the first target we may have BASE_URL = @"https://firsttarget.com/", whereas if the environment is the second target we may have BASE_URL = @"https://secondtarget.com/".

For legal purposes, if someone were to recompile the assembly, and go hunting to strings etc... we cannot have somebody finding the string @"https://firsttarget.com/" if they were looking into the binary for the second target app.

So my question is... are strings behind preprocessor conditionals removed during Archive if they are not relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sections in code between `#ifdef` and `#endif` (or `#else`) are not seen by the compiler unless the symbol given on the ifdef line is defined. You can easily show this by writing something that won't compile in such a section. And since the compiler doesn't see that code there is no way the value of that define can end up in the binary.

To see exactly what the compiler will work with you can select an implementation file in Xcode and chose "Product > Perform Action > Preprocess" from the menu. This will show you exactly what the compiler will work with. Of course there will also be the content from all the system .h files that are imported, so your code most likely is at the very end. Your `#define` lines will be stripped too, so to really check which strings will be used you need to chose a file that actually uses those macros.

And finally you can do the same thing an attacker might do - use the `strings` utility on the compiled binary and see what's in there. In Xcode build your app and select the "Show in Finder" option for your app bundle from the products group. There select "Show package contents" to open app your actual app bundle. The actual binary is in there with the same name as your bundle but no file extension. Then open a terminal window, type "strings " (that is the word strings followed by a space) and drag the binary on top of this. Then confirm with return. You will get a long list of every readable string from the binary (including every selector).

Comment: can you explain more about using the strings utility to see what's in the compiled binary.